# Sorting a dictionary by value descending then key descending

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a dictionary where the value is a list of two elements where I need to sort the second element (a number) in descending order. I then want the key to be in descending order as well. I thought this would do it..

```
users = sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

and while the list is in descending order of the number the names are still in ascending order whenever there is a tie. Should I be handling it differently?

Comment: It would help if you added some example input and (current and expected) output.

Comment: @LutzHorn I'm just trying to sort the dictionary to then write the ouptut.  sorted returns a list so why would "dict has no order" be relevant?  It sorts by value ok. It's when trying to sort then by key is an issue.

Comment: I get what you're saying.  I was responding to the now deleted comment. I'm not sure why it's not working out on my end as expected. I'll try to come up with an example bit given your answer I'm not sure if i can but I'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for me, your code works as expected:

```
users = {"a": (0, 0), "b": (0, 1), "c": (0, 1)}
sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], x[0]), reverse=True)
[('c', (0, 1)), ('b', (0, 1)), ('a', (0, 0))]
```

It first sorts by the value in the second position and for a tie it sorts by the key.

Comment: It had to do with precision for the number.  It just so happens that all the ones I checked ended up in ascending order for name when there were ties from rounding values